# What kind of content does Apple host for in-app purchases, and under which conditions?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I've heard that Apple offers hosting content for in-app purchases. We are working on an app where users can purchase small video clips of about 5 MB each.

I couldn't find detailed information about the conditions what Apple hosts, how they host it, and how much they charge for it. Some developers say it is only available in iOS 6. This is confusing.

Is it also possible to host content at Apple which users can simply download without in-app purchases?

Can in-app purchases be free?

Can someone clarify and provide links to official information from Apple?

Answer (score 7):

you can find some information about conditions in this document (page 30) - [Using Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf)

It's free, but you can host not more than 2 GB per package (the same limit for an application)

Useful articles: [Configuring and Creating App Store Hosted Content for iOS 6 In-App Purchases](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases) and [Changes to StoreKit](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Platform_Features/Introduction_to_iOS_6/Changes_to_StoreKit)

Hosted content works only for Non-Consumable purchases, which cannot be free. So I think it's not possible to host some free content there.

Comment: What does "per package" mean? Per app? Or per purchase item?

Comment: @ProudMember per app (and consequently per each purchase item in an application).

Comment: do you know what kind of content comes when you download? Zip? Pkg? what?

Comment: @RubberDuck it's zip file with two things inside:  1) ContentInfo.plist with some metadata about your In-App Purchase; 2) Contents directory.

Comment: @BurundukXP thanks. I have asked this because I am receiving a folder named com.mycompany.myapp.myinapp.zip pretending to be a zip with the structure you say. I thought it was a zip, because it has the zip extension, but it is a folder. This app is for iOS 6. I suppose iOS 6 unzips the received folder automatically or I am seeing some magic going on.

Comment: @RubberDuck yes, it should uzip it automatically. not sure about the name - need to check. but, yes, obviously it should be uziped.

Comment: @BurundukXP - are you really sure iOS unzips the package automatically? I was considering this to be some problem with my uploaded package...

Comment: @DmitryKhryukin Where did you read that Non-Consumable purchases can't be free? I have been looking for this piece of information everywhere but I couldn't find anything in regards to it. I am asking you because I am having the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133222/free-non-consumable-in-app-purchase-with-hosted-content-on-appless-servers. If what you say is true, iTunes connect has got a bug because it let's you create free Non-Consumable in-app purchases.