# Free non-consumable in-app purchase with hosted content on Apples's servers

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

Can non-consumable in-app purchases that include content hosted on Apple's servers be free?

I couldn't find anything about this in the docs and as you can set in-app purchases to be free in iTunes connect, I assumed it was possible.

I have set up a non-consumable in-app purchase on iTunes connect, uploaded some content and set its price to be free.

Unfortunately when I request the products data using the product ID, I receive that ID in the SKProductsResponse.invalidProductIdentifiers array.

I have also set up another in-app purchase different from the previous one only in the price, as its price tier is Tier 1 rather than Free. This one works just fine.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html), In order for a download object to be queued, it must be associated with a transaction that has been successfully purchased, but not yet finished.

For free data hosting why you dont want to use your own server?

Comment: I cannot create a transaction if the product ID is returned as an invalid one by Store Kit in the SKProductsResponse. I don't have my own server and uploading my app's content to Apple's servers seems the easiest solution.